# OrderByDescending with Skip and Take in LINQ shows error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

My linq is something

```
GetPublishedArticleList().Where(x => x.Category.CatName == catName).OrderByDescending(x=>x.PublishedDate).Skip(skip).Take(last);
```

I am getting following exception when the above code is run

"The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Well I want LINQ to understand that I need to order the data in descending order first and then can apply Skip and Take. (well the above code works when OrderByDescending is replaced by OrderBy)

Can someone suggest me alternative ?

Comment: Could you call Take first? That will return you an IEnumerable (from an IOrderedQueryable) on which you can call Skip. If that will mess with your indicies, you could change it to `Take(skip + last).Skip(skip)`

Comment: Wow - that's really odd. It *sounds* like a bug to me...

Comment: @John: No, calling `Take` first would break the results... and the point is that we've got an `IOrderedQueryable` here, not an `IOrderedEnumerable` - we're trying to reduce the amount of data transferred from the database.

Comment: @JonSkeet got it, and I couldn't remember, I was too lazy to check the docs

Comment: @JonSkeet is right. Just in case if anyone have doubt GetPublishedArticleList() is nothing but context.TableName

Comment: @John: My point was your claim that having an `IEnumerable` would be a good thing. If you cast the result of `OrderByDescending` to `IEnumerable<T>` then `Skip`/`Take` will work - but only by fetching a load of data and discarding it. The point of building up an `IQueryable<T>` is that it can be converted into SQL for the database. Whether you call `Enumerable.Skip` or `Queryable.Skip` makes a *huge* amount of difference to how much data will be transferred from the database when the results are first used.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I jumped the gun on the last comment, I didn't read the `entity-framework` tag. I've ran into this same problem in the past and never solved it.

Comment: @John: Right. It really does sound like an EF issue.

Comment: What is method signature? Does it return IQueryable or IEnumerable? Do you have any other extension method? Right click on OrderByDescending and Click on Go to definition and tell us what you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with EF5. (.net 4.5) 
I cant see anything wrong with your code.
Are you sure you had the method sequence right when testing ?
Was the source type Iqueryable or Iqueryable ?

```
public virtual IQueryable<TPoco> GetSortedPageList<TSortKey>(Expression<Func<TPoco, bool>>    predicate,
        Expression<Func<TPoco, TSortKey>> sortBy,
        bool descending,
        int skipRecords, int takeRecords) {
        if (!descending) {
            return Context.Set<TPoco>()
                 .Where<TPoco> predicate)
                .OrderBy(sortBy)
                .Skip(skipRecords)
                .Take(takeRecords);
        }
        return
            Context.Set<TPoco>()
                .Where<TPoco>(predicate)
                .OrderByDescending(sortBy)
                .Skip(skipRecords)
                .Take(takeRecords);
    }
```

Comment: the source type is IQueryable. yeah the method sequence is correct at my end. I have EF5 too. this is very strange.

Comment: That is a concern.  I just wrote a Test to make descending worked. It did.  But im worried that there is an issue somewhere. You didnt by chance when you ran your test, have the list built with distinct or group ? Im trying to dream up why it might fail. struggling....

Comment: i found 2 issues one with EF dll not reference properly and I was applying Where clause 2 times. Now updated EF from Nuget and merged those 2 Where clause from 2 different place(different child methods) to one.